# Matching a datetime against a date in django

Tags: python, django

I have a django model with a `DateTimeField` called `when` which I want to match against a `Date` object.  Is there a way to do that in django's queryset language better than

```
Samples.objects.filter( when__gte = mydate, when__lt = mydate + datetime.timedelta(1) )
```

Comment: Not sure if this can be applied to help:  http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.QuerySet.dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same like W_P, off the top of my head:

```
Samples.objects.filter(when__year = mydate.year, when__month = mydate.month, when__day = mydate.day)
```

You can round that up to year, month, day. This is the way I create posts archive in my code. I have three options: yearly archive, monthly archive and daily archive. The difference between them is the combination of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Just off the top of my head, I suppose you could do this:

```
def tomorrow(dt):
    return dt + datetime.timedelta(1)

# ...

Samples.objects.filter( when__gte = mydate, when__lt = tomorrow(mydate) )
```

I know it doesn't really *solve* your problem, but at least it looks nicer...